# Why is my component not updating in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, web, vue-component

I'm switching from React to Vue and I just can't force my component to update. Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      jobs: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  updated(){
    console.log('Updated: ' + this.jobs);//cant log this
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch('jobs.json');
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);//json array. This logs fine
      this.jobs.push(...data);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.first-row {
  padding-top: 10%;
}
</style>
```

I can't invoke update method and thus can't log my data. Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: With your template, there is no patching or rendering necessary so there are no updates, hence you not seeing the updated method fire.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought it just works like Reacts useEffect :)

Comment: If you `watch`ed `jobs` instead of listening to `updated` you might see the difference.

Comment: For reference, you *usually* (like, 99% of the time) shouldn't need to force an update in Vue, because of its reactivity system. If you do find yourself needing to, it often means you've missed something in regards to how Vue reactivity works, more times than not one of Vue's documented [reactivity caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). | Related article: [The correct way to force Vue to re-render a component](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/)